# Compare two datatable and set its value

Tags: c#, performance, datatable, compare

i have 2 datatable which i only need to compare one column cell value. check if it equals then get the cell value of dt2 and set it on dt. here what i got so far. it is working as expected but took a long time doing so because of its large entries from both datatable.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow row2 in dt2.Rows)
    {
        if (row[0].ToString().Equals(row2[0].ToString()))
        {
            row[1] = row2[1];
            row[68] = row2[59];
        }
    }
}
```

how do i increase the performance for this? i am not experience enough to use and knowing about linq or others..any example that working the same way as this would be appreciate. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this LINQ approach is little bit faster because it's a set based approach:

```
var updateRows = from r1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
                 join r2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                 on r1.Field<string>(0) equals r2.Field<string>(0)
                 select new { r1, r2 };

foreach(var x in updateRows)
{
    x.r1.SetField(1, x.r2[1]);
    x.r1.SetField(68, x.r2[59]);
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer..my question is..will this do update the dt as well?

Comment: @ZulfakarZukri: have you seen the `foreach`-loop which will enumerate the LINQ query `updateRows`? `SetField` will update the value, but you could also use your way `row[1] = row2[1]`.

Comment: yes i do, i just getting confused how LINQ works..however your code working and very fast lol..thank you..i need to learn more